# What does this mean? "alienPosition = alien.position"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Can someone please tell me what this means and how to fix i?   "Alien" is a sprite, and the alienPosition variable is assigned a double.

```
alienPosition = alien.position
```

The error says this

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'CGPoint' to a value of type 'Double'
```

Comment: `alienPosition` should be of type `CGPoint` not `Double`

Comment: @tumber033 The other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position property of a sprite is a [CGPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGPoint) giving both the x and y coordinates of the sprite. You cannot assign this to a variable or constant of type double.

So change the declaration of alienPosition to be a CGPoint and then access the individual components as alienPosition.x and alienPosition.y (which are both of type CGFloat).

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: However, now I am getting a strange error on the class GameScene bit saying, that it has no initializers, this is new, would it have any connection tot he changes I made?

Comment: @JamesEllsworth probably indirectly. I guess you have declared a new property but not set its value in an initialiser? All non optional properties need to be set to an initial value either as part of their declaration or in the init method for the class. But it is probably better to ask a new question showing your code and the error.